# unable to post multipart/form-data to an endpoint using wmMediator

Tags: mediator, webmethods

I encountered a problem with Mediator (9.7 with Fix 11) package, and I would like to know if you have encountered the same thing or if you have some ideas to correct or get around it ?

The problem is : I have a http REST-like request, which is in fact a multipart/form-data page. When I call it by Mediator (virtualized with Centrasite), the multipart payload is transformed in xml format. The endpoint is not able to respond correctly with that format.

Why mediator do this transformation and how can we prevent it ?

In Mediator input, we have this :

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----    WebKitFormBoundaryiBMdnONIEM1rPnWp\r\n
------WebKitFormBoundaryiBMdnONIEM1rPnWp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="typeEnvoi"
99
------WebKitFormBoundaryiBMdnONIEM1rPnWp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="prenom"
hhhh
------WebKitFormBoundaryiBMdnONIEM1rPnWp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileVisualExam1";     filename="Mezer_Stamp.png"
Content-Type: image/png
?PNG
```

The endpoint recieve that :

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><tns:POST_AppMobile
 xmlns:tns="http://namespaces.compagny.com/wsdl">    
<typeEnvoi>99</typeEnvoi>     
<fileVisualExam1>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF4AAABZCAYAAAC315PWAAAAAXNSR0IArs
4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAARZSURBVHja7NAJAQAwEAIg+5
[...] Wp70lgEAafIxtwjUN/HS1B12VkNYiYm0i9wcjG1+yo+S9ZjauIsIDRm5RobKkeQoQ2fYxx9DUmU5S9Kx
T8QwYfynJcRoSFgt6mVKqxBdehf4bx9B7G0A+Y6r6ra9R1VdvI=</fileVisualExam1>    
<prenom>hhhh</prenom></tns:POST_AppMobile>
```

I have made some attemps by modifying the content-types.xml config file for mediator (adding multipart or binary for that mime), but without success.

Comment: Which version of Mediator are using? Which fix level?

Comment: 9.7 with fix 11. I have edited the question to add this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the latest Mediator 9.7 Fix (currently fix 18). As of Fix 15, the following issue has been resolved:

```
SMGME-5868 (Fix 15)
Mediator transforms rest request of type multipart/form-data to XML.

When requests with multipart/form-data are sent to Mediator, Mediator converts 
the request to application/xml. This issue is resolved
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I will try to have and install this fix. Thank you